# Do all ignored tags get blurred out, or do they not show up anymore?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I blocked some tags just a few minutes ago, but right after I ignored it, a user had an upload for it, it was faded out but still quite noticeable.  After that question, will no more show up, or will they always be just faded out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions with ignored tags will be faded out unless you choose to hide them completely from *profile > preferences*.

[image: Ignored Tags \ Add \ hide ignored tags]